# Use paste inside datatables, with a string vector as an input

Tags: r, data.table, paste

```
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

data(iris)
iris <- iris %>% as.data.table()

iris[ , pasted := paste(Species, Petal.Width)]
```

I would like an alternative of the above function so as the inputs of the paste function to be in a string vector. (The reason is that I may rerun the script and the names or numbers of variables in the paste function may differ ever time.

I tried the following

```
names <- c('Species', "Petal.Width") 
iris[ , pasted := paste(names %>% get())]
```

or with using the .SD

```
 dt[, pasted:=paste0(.SD), .SDcols = names]
```

but they do not  work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way, but this works: `iris[ , pasted := paste(names[1] %>% get, names[2] %>% get) ]`

Comment: `iris[, pasted := do.call(paste, .SD), .SDcols = names]`

Comment: Or `iris[, pasted := do.call(paste, mget(names))]` perhaps?

Comment: In base R `iris$pasted <- apply(iris, 1, Reduce, f = paste)`

Comment: @RobJensen, `do.call` is a bit more idiomatic here. `iris$pasted <- do.call(paste, iris[names])`.

Comment: You can also do `iris[, pasted := do.call(paste, .SD[, ..names])]`, though I just discovered this `..` syntax by error message and have no idea where it's documented.

Comment: @alistaire There was announcement in the "Changes in v1.10.2 (on CRAN 31 Jan 2017)" News section of `data.table`'s wiki: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md, but I can't seem to find a reference in the help pages.

Comment: @alistaire Thank you for your answer! if you please write it down as an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a vector to `.SDcols`, `.SD` is a data frame (and therefore list) of those columns. You can't directly `paste` a data frame usefully, which is why the original code fails.

You *can*, however, use `do.call` to invoke a function like `paste` on a list to be passed as parameters, e.g.

```r
library(data.table)

# passing parameters directly to `paste` works...
paste(x = c('a', 'b'), y = c(1, 2))
#> [1] "a 1" "b 2"

# ...but passing it a data frame gets weird (working in series instead of parallel)...
paste(data.table(x = c('a', 'b'), y = c(1, 2)))
#> [1] "c(\"a\", \"b\")" "c(1, 2)"

# ...so `do.call` turns the call here into the first version
do.call(paste, data.table(x = c('a', 'b'), y = c(1, 2)))
#> [1] "a 1" "b 2"
```

In context, then,

```r
data(iris)
setDT(iris)
cols <- c("Species", "Petal.Width")

iris[, pasted := do.call(paste, .SD), .SDcols = cols]

iris[, c(cols, "pasted"), with = FALSE]
#>        Species Petal.Width        pasted
#>   1:    setosa         0.2    setosa 0.2
#>   2:    setosa         0.2    setosa 0.2
#>   3:    setosa         0.2    setosa 0.2
#>   4:    setosa         0.2    setosa 0.2
#>   5:    setosa         0.2    setosa 0.2
#>  ---                                    
#> 146: virginica         2.3 virginica 2.3
#> 147: virginica         1.9 virginica 1.9
#> 148: virginica         2.0   virginica 2
#> 149: virginica         2.3 virginica 2.3
#> 150: virginica         1.8 virginica 1.8
```

Alternatives to using `.SDcols` are the experimental `..` notation:

```r
iris[, pasted := do.call(paste, .SD[, ..cols])]
```

or Ananda's elegant `mget`, which returns a list of the variable whose names you pass it:

```r
iris[, pasted := do.call(paste, mget(cols))]
```

All return the same thing.